# Symfony4 JMS\Serializer\SerializedName will be ignored on deserialize()

Tags: symfony, symfony4, jmsserializerbundle

I have a JSON that will be `deserialize()` with JMS.

The JSON looks like

```
{  
  "creator": [
    {
      "value": 234,
      "label": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "value": 223,
      "label": "World"
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON will be deserialized with my created Model

```php
$this->serializer->deserialize($json, Model::class, 'json');
```

and my Model class has:

```php
    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     */
    private $creator;
```

This works perfectly fine, the deserializer convert the JSON into my Model and I receive `creator` with array-items.

I would like to change the variable name from `creator` to `customer` in my model. I was thinking it works with the annotation `@Serializer\SerializedName()`.

But when im using this

```
    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("customer")
     */
    private $creator;
```

the model will be not filled at all.

Do I fundamentally misunderstand this function?

Comment: Did you want to change the key used in the JSON string or the property of your class?

Comment: @xabbuh the property name in my class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@Serializer\SerializedName("creator")` and `$customer` then?

Comment: @xabbuh No, he's completely ignoring that.

Comment: Could you update your question with how the JSON you want to deserialize looks like and how your PHP class looks like now?